# Changing pixel type of image in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am a student and new Google Earth Engine user.

I need to convert the pixel type of image from 16 bit to 8 bit to calculate Forest Canopy Density in google earth engine. I am seeking a way to solve this problem.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no repeatable code above, but this should get you started: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_visualization

```
var imageRGB = image.visualize({bands: ['B5', 'B4', 'B3'], max: 0.5});
var ndwiRGB = ndwiMasked.visualize({
  min: 0.5,
  max: 1,
  palette: ['00FFFF', '0000FF']
});
```

The image.visualize() function converts images to 8-bit.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is helpful for me. Have a nice day.